# How to Count and Plot Interval Time Series Data (Hourly) in Python)?

Tags: python, plot, time-series, intervals

I have accident Time Series data (YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS. I can count all the data based on weekday, year, hour, but I am trying to to count between 8 and 17 hours. Also, want to plot and show the counted numbers range as 8-10, 10-12, 12-13, 13-15, 15-17.

My codes;

```
df = pd.read_excel("C:/Users/gokhankazar/Desktop/Accident Times/Accident_Time-Series.xlsx")
df["Hour"] = df.Datetime.dt.hour
df.Hour.value_counts().sort_index().plot(marker='o', linestyle='-')
plt.xlabel('Hours', fontsize=10)
plt.ylabel("Number of Accident", fontsize= 10)
plt.show()
```

And I got plot figure as below
[My figure that I got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hTxY8.png)

But how can I change my axis range in plot figure.

Also I have weekdays figure as like
[WeekDay figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uUeDO.png)

I want to write on x axis Monday instead of "0" and Sunday instead of "6" with all other days

my Datetime column as (total 268000 rows) and just counting the accident event based on time series data

```
18.05.2015  09:00:00
18.05.2015  15:00:00
18.05.2015  14:14:00
18.05.2015  09:00:00
.
.
.
```

Comment: you can use `df.Datetime.between_time('8:00', '17:00')`

Comment: thank you luigigi, but it gives datetimeIndex error.

Comment: @GokhanKazar can you post or give link to raw data?  In first plot with hours you try to group data by 2 h and plot that with proper ticks?

Comment: @ZarakiKenpachi I edited my question and put my datetime column. thank you.

Comment: @GokhanKazar post this data as text inside you question. What about my second question?

Comment: @ZarakiKenpachi for second question, actually I am trying to plot range hour with sums. For example number of counts between 8-10 am, write the counted value on 8 am. I am sending as text my raw data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to group you data by every 2h and set proper ticks for you plot.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['18.05.2015 09:00:00','18.05.2015 15:00:00', '18.05.2015 14:14:00', '18.05.2015 11:00:00']})

# convert to datetime
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
# group time every 2h
df = df.groupby(df.date.dt.floor('2H')).count()

# plot data
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax1.set_xticks(np.arange(8, 15, 2))
ax1.set_xticklabels(['8-10', '10-12', '12-14', '14-16'])
plt.plot(df.index.hour, df.date, '.')
plt.show()
```

**OUtput:**

[image]